# Action Bar Tab must have a Callback addTab error

Tags: java, android

My problem is in the addTab() method, but I dont know how to solve it.

This is the error log:

```
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{yab.example.viewpager1/yab.example.viewpager1.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121) 10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2146)
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140) 10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Action Bar Tab must have a Callback 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.configureTab(ActionBarImpl.java:488) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:514) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.addTab(ActionBarImpl.java:502) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at yab.example.viewpager1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2085) 
10-12 02:19:43.750: E/AndroidRuntime(22899): ... 11 more
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.viewpager3;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private ViewPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new
                ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.hello_world));
//      for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
//          Toast.makeText(this, "hello "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//          //actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)));
//          }
//      mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new
//              ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
//              @Override
//              public void onPageSelected(int position) {
//                  Log.i("test de problème", "problème");
//              actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
//              Log.i("test de problème", "no problème");
//              
//              }
//              });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that action bar tabs are deprecated in the "L" Developer Preview and should remain deprecated in the next production release of Android. You may wish to consider other tab solutions (e.g., `ViewPager` and a tabbed indicator) or alternative navigation solutions (e.g., a navigation drawer).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't set the listener.

Use this:

```
ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
tab.setText(R.string.hello_world);
tab.setTabListener(this)
actionBar.addTab(tab);
```